# Cant enter ec2 machine anymore

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I uploaded a python script that uses selenium, chromedriver and chromium to scrape information from the web to a linux ec2 machine.

I tried to run the .py file in the ec2 machine. Nothing happened, no error message or something else. Curser jumped into the next line, without having the ubuntu@... infront of it.

So i closed the terminal and tried to enter the ec2 machine again. But now nothing happens again. Trying to open the ec2 with verbose gives me this.

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-3-138-107-26.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file aws_key.pem type -1
debug1: identity file aws_key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
```

This is now for 15min already.
What happened or what can i do?

Comment: I'd restart the EC2 instance and then try again in a tmux session, so that way you can track whether or not the script finished. Does the script do a similar thing when run locally?

Comment: Thx, i will try this. But what do you mean with tmux session? How do i do this? Locally the script is working perfectly. On ec2 i had some chromdriver problems tried different arguments and with the last try, the problems with the ec2 machine occured. Maybe selenium worked in the last try but ran into an unfinit loop.

Comment: [this](https://danielmiessler.com/study/tmux/) could help you get set up with using tmux. But sounds like your code probably did reach an infinite loop. However without seeing the code, or what you had to change to get it to work on EC2, it's only guesswork as to how to fix the issue.